# Parse Issue: Module not found

Tags: database, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.1

I am making an app that will use a database to connect to, I have come across Parse seen as I have used this before.

But when I try to add the 'setApplicationId' Xcode doesn't recognise Parse.

I have added a bridging header containing  Parse/Parse.h in <> and the same with bolts!

Then I add all the correct frameworks from the Parse QuickStart Guide!

But still an error!

Thnx,
AppSwiftGB

Comment: Can you give us more info about your error?

Comment: It says Parse has no member named...

Comment: Does anyone know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: you got solution?